# Delphi 6 and Indy SSL connection not working

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I need to consume a Web Service via SSL. In order to accomplish that I have built a web client in Delphi 6 that uses Indy to read the client certificates and write the soap request via https. The compilated version of the code is a DLL that runs in IIS 5.0. After tested the code in my local machine it works fine (I'm behind a proxy). But after the code is deployed to prod servers (not proxy) the SSL connection fails saying "Error connecting with SSL".

Here is my code:

```
var
  Response: TStringStream;
  IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
  IdCnxSLL: TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL;
  XmlSoapDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  Response := TStringStream.Create('');
  IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdCnxSLL := TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  XmlSoapDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  with IdCnxSLL do
   begin
    IdCnxSLL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    IdCnxSLL.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := IniHttpConnectionData.Values['RootCertFile'];
    IdCnxSLL.SSLOptions.CertFile := IniHttpConnectionData.Values['CertFile'];
    IdCnxSLL.SSLOptions.KeyFile := IniHttpConnectionData.Values['KeyFile'];
    IdCnxSLL.OnGetPassword :=  IdConInterceptOpenSSLGetPassword;
  end;
  with IdHttp do
  begin
    if bUseProxy then
    begin
       Request.ProxyServer := IniHttpConnectionData.Values['ProxyServer'];
       Request.ProxyPort := StrToIntDef(IniHttpConnectionData.Values['ProxyPort'], 0);
    end
    else
    begin
       Host := IniHttpConnectionData.Values['HTTPHost'];
       Port := StrToIntDef(IniHttpConnectionData.Values['HTTPPort'], 443);
    end;
    Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    Intercept := IdCnxSLL;
    InterceptEnabled := True;
  end;

  try
    IdHttp.Post(ServiceURL, SoapEnv, Response);
  except
    on E:EIdOSSLConnectError do
       LogError('SSL Connect Error: ' + E.Message);
    on E:Exception do
      LogError('Error' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
  end;
```

I also try this code compiling into an exe program and it works. Is there something else I need to configure/add?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what is IniHttpConnectionData in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnally It worked. Although I strongly encourage you to use a newer version of Indy as Remy suggests. I will post the steps that did the trick for me since there should be other people with the same problem.

The original code I posted is functional, it works when we need to post information via secured http (https) but the remote server requires prior authentification using a client certificate.

In order to make it work, it is necessary to verify the following:

1. TIdHttp and TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL configuration
2. Certificates

For the first 2 steps follow the steps mentioned here [link text](http://blog.csdn.net/happy4nothing/archive/2004/12/01/201265.aspx) or (in case link is expired) Google "IndySSL - using certificate authentication". It worked for me.

3. Indy SSL DLLs. (For D6/Indy 8 download indy_openssl096g.zip from [Indy SSL](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/SSL.en.aspx) or [Intelicom](http://www.intelicom.si/www.nsf/sub?readform&cat=9&lang=en)) This DLLs where the only ones that worked for this version of Indy.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Helped me. Thank you.

Comment: The last two links are dead by now.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are using TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL tells me that you are using a **VERY** old version of Indy.  I am guessing Indy 8, which shipped with D6.  Indy 8 and earlier are no longer officially supported by the Indy development team (which I am a member of).  You really should upgrade to Indy 9, if not to Indy 10.  In Indy 9, TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL was replaced with a new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket component.  Also, Indy 9 and earlier required custom-made OpenSSL DLLs, which may be contributing to your error as well, if you are using the wrong DLLs for your version of Indy.  Indy 10, on the other hand, uses the standard DLLs from OpenSSL's website now.

Comment: You are right, I'm working on D6/Indy 8. I can't update to indy 9 or 10 since there are some existing apps that uses this version of Delphi and Indy.

For future new developments I will definitely switch to Indy 10. Thanks for your reply.